# Custom UITableViewCell resize according to screen size

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, interface-builder, autolayout, custom-cell

I just made a subclass of the UITableViewCell which contains 5 labels in row:

[image]

Width of it is 320 what is a width of iPhone 4S. I have a problem when I load a table view with this cell on device with bigger screen. There is a long space between last label ("XX" in the picture) and end of the cell.

What I want to achieve is that I want to have the same space between labels and first/last label and beginning/end of the cell. Each label has different size. So basically I can say that I want to have regular table with columns.

I tried to do it using auto layout but without success. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want the following:
All your labels should have a fixed horizontal distance to its neighbors. The labels themselves have different widths. If you change the screen width, the ratio between their widths should be constant. If so, you could do:
Add in storyboard for all labels constraints that fix their horizontal distance to their next neighbors. Then set for all labels a constraint of equal width. Since you don't want equal widths, edit for each label the equal width constraint, and change the multiplier from its standard value 1 to the required value. The constraint is then no longer named "equal width" but "proportional width". This should do it.